# MPAndroidChart auto zoom BarChart on x-axis

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

i'm looking at mpAndroidChart library for draw some charts, and i've this code (for a barchart):

```
chart.setDescription("");
chart.setDrawVerticalGrid(false);
chart.setDrawGridBackground(false);
chart.setDrawBarShadow(false);
chart.setDrawLegend(false);

XLabels xl = holder.chart.getXLabels();
xl.setCenterXLabelText(true);
xl.setPosition(XLabelPosition.BOTTOM);
xl.setTextSize(20f);

YLabels yl = holder.chart.getYLabels();
yl.setLabelCount(5);
yl.setTextSize(20f);

// set data
chart.setData((BarData) mChartData);
holder.chart.setScaleMinima(2f, 0f);

chart.animateY(700);
```

now when chart is showed, bars are zoomed in but they are zoomed too much.
In fact i can zoom out (until zoom fit setScaleMinima value for x).
I would that when chart is showed, zoom is exactly what i've declared inside setScaleMinima. How can i do that?

Comment: Setting scale minima to 0f means you can zoom out too infinity. Setting it to 1f means you can zoom out exactly as much to see the whole chart.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Setting scale minima to 0f means you can zoom out too infinity. Setting it to 1f means you can zoom out exactly as much to see the whole chart.

So you should call:

`setScaleMinima(2f, 1f)`

which only sets the zoom bounds, but does no actual zooming.

Then use the method

`zoom(...)`to zoom in to wherever you want.

Comment: Hi, I am using your library for android and am getting an issue as posted here http://stackoverflow.com/q/39589620/1503130 . Can you please guide me on the same.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the BarChart library but it is pretty easy to implement one on your own.
I'll paste snippets of one, i recently made, hope this helps.

```
package com.example.preferencestest.util;

import com.example.preferencestest.R;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.content.res.TypedArray;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.View;

public class MyCustomChartView extends View {
    private int width=0, height=0;

    public MyCustomChartView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        setup(null);
    }

    public MyCustomChartView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        setup(attrs);
    }
    public MyCustomChartView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        setup(attrs);
    }

    private int firstValue=0, secondValue=0, thirdValue=0, horizontalPadding=20, verticalPadding=40;
    private String title="";
    private Paint outerLine, grid, other;
    private Resources res;

    private void setup(AttributeSet attrs) {
        if (attrs != null) {
            Context ctx = getContext();
            TypedArray ta = ctx.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.MyCustomCharView);
            firstValue = ta.getInt(R.styleable.MyCustomCharView_Plot_First_Value, firstValue);
            secondValue = ta.getInt(R.styleable.MyCustomCharView_Plot_Second_Value, secondValue);
            thirdValue = ta.getInt(R.styleable.MyCustomCharView_Plot_Third_Value, thirdValue);
            ta.recycle();
        }
        res = getResources();
        outerLine = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
        outerLine.setColor(res.getColor(R.color.plot_outer_line));
        outerLine.setStrokeWidth(3);
        grid = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
        grid.setColor(res.getColor(R.color.plot_grid));
        grid.setStrokeWidth(2);
        other = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
        super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
        width = w; height = h;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        //float width = canvas.getWidth(), height = canvas.getHeight();
        int limit = Math.max(6, Math.max(firstValue, Math.max(secondValue, thirdValue)));
        canvas.drawLine(horizontalPadding, verticalPadding, 
                horizontalPadding, height-verticalPadding, outerLine);
        canvas.drawLine(horizontalPadding, height-verticalPadding, 
                width-horizontalPadding, height-verticalPadding, outerLine);

        int gridVertMargin = Math.round((height-(verticalPadding*2))/7);
        for (int i=0; i<7; i++) {
            canvas.drawLine(horizontalPadding+1, 
                    verticalPadding+(i*gridVertMargin), 
                    width-horizontalPadding, 
                    verticalPadding+(i*gridVertMargin), grid);
        }

        int gridHoriMargin = Math.round((width-(horizontalPadding*2))/limit);
        for (int i = 0; i < limit; i++) {
            canvas.drawLine(horizontalPadding+((i+1)*gridHoriMargin), 
                    verticalPadding+1, 
                    horizontalPadding+((i+1)*gridHoriMargin), 
                    height-verticalPadding, grid);
            canvas.drawText(String.valueOf(i+1), horizontalPadding+((i+1)*gridHoriMargin)-2, height-(verticalPadding/2), outerLine);
        }

        other.setColor(res.getColor(R.color.plot_first_color));
        if (this.firstValue > 0) {
            canvas.drawRect(horizontalPadding+1, 
                    verticalPadding+(gridVertMargin*1)+1, 
                    this.firstValue*gridHoriMargin+horizontalPadding-1, 
                    verticalPadding+(gridVertMargin*2)-1, other);
        }

        other.setColor(res.getColor(R.color.plot_second_color));
        if (this.secondValue > 0) {
            canvas.drawRect(horizontalPadding+1, 
                    verticalPadding+(gridVertMargin*3)+1, 
                    this.secondValue*gridHoriMargin+horizontalPadding-1, 
                    verticalPadding+(gridVertMargin*4)-1, other);
        }

        other.setColor(res.getColor(R.color.plot_third_color));
        if (this.thirdValue > 0) {
            canvas.drawRect(horizontalPadding+1, 
                    verticalPadding+(gridVertMargin*5)+1, 
                    this.thirdValue*gridHoriMargin+horizontalPadding-1, 
                    verticalPadding+(gridVertMargin*6)-1, other);
        }
    }

    public int getFirstValue() {
        return firstValue;
    }

    public void setFirstValue(int first) {
        if (this.firstValue != first) {
            this.firstValue = first;
            invalidate();
        }
    }

    public int getSecondValue() {
        return secondValue;
    }

    public void setSecondValue(int second) {
        if (this.secondValue != second) {
            this.secondValue = second;
            invalidate();
        }
    }

    public int getThirdValue() {
        return thirdValue;
    }

    public void setThirdValue(int third) {
        if (this.thirdValue != third) {
            this.thirdValue = third;
            invalidate();
        }
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        if (! this.title.equals(title)) {
            this.title = title;
            invalidate();
        }
    }
}
```

you will need a xml file for the xml styleable values (first, second and third bar in this case) like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <declare-styleable name="MyCustomCharView">
        <attr name="Plot_First_Value" format="integer" />
        <attr name="Plot_Second_Value" format="integer" />
        <attr name="Plot_Third_Value" format="integer" />
    </declare-styleable>

    <color name="plot_outer_line">#330000</color>
    <color name="plot_grid">#dd0000</color>
    <color name="plot_first_color">#99aa00</color>
    <color name="plot_second_color">#770000</color>
    <color name="plot_third_color">#00ee77</color>
</resources>
```

And finally you may add your new BarChart like this to your Layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/[yourpackage]">

        <[yourpackage].MyCustomChartView
            android:id="@+id/row_plot"
            style="@style/ListItem"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            title=""
            app:Plot_First_Value="15"
            app:Plot_Second_Value="1"
            app:Plot_Third_Value="3" />
{...}
```

Comment: barchart is not the library, is an object to create a barChart of  mpAndroidchart library

Comment: When i wrote this View, i didn't know mpAndroidchart or it wasn't available. However it seems that the example handles many zoom types and events. As found on the projects github page: `The corresponding code for the demo-application is also included in this repository inside the MPChartExample folder.` 
there you may find source for auto handling the zoom level.

Answer (score 0):

Your can use following methods for you task

**Restraining what's visible**

1. setVisibleXRangeMaximum(float maxXRange): Sets the size of the area (range on the x-axis) that should be maximum visible at once. If this is e.g. set to 10, no more than 10 values on the x-axis can be viewed at once without scrolling.
2. setVisibleXRangeMinimum(float minXRange): Sets the size of the area (range on the x-axis) that should be minimum visible at once. If this is e.g. set to 10, it is not possible to zoom in further than 10 values on the x-axis.
3. setVisibleYRangeMaximum(float maxYRange, AxisDependency axis): Sets the size of the area (range on the y-axis) that should be maximum visible at once. You also need to provide the axis this constraint should apply to.
4. setViewPortOffsets(float left, float top, float right, float bottom): Sets custom offsets for the current ViewPort (the offsets on the sides of the actual chart window). Setting this will prevent the chart from automatically calculating it's offsets. Use resetViewPortOffsets() to undo this. USE THIS ONLY WHEN YOU KNOW WHAT YOU ARE DOING.
   5.resetViewPortOffsets(): Resets all custom offsets set via setViewPortOffsets(...) method. Allows the chart to again calculate all offsets automatically.
5. setExtraOffsets(float left, float top, float right, float bottom): Sets extra offsets (around the chart view) to be appended to the auto-calculated offsets. This does not change the auto-calculated offsets, but adds extra space to them.